# TFS 2010: Seeing and comparing changes after getting latest

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I get latest from TFS source control, I don't see the changes made to my workspace.

I know I can go to the Output window and see the changes, but this is just a text list with no context actions.

What I really want is to see a list of changes, with the ability to right-click a file and see differences straight away.

Is there a better, alternative way to see changes like this after getting latest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like using the command line tool tf.exe with [folderdiff command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385992.aspx) would achieve what you need.

> Use the folderdiff command to display
>   and compare a visual representation of
>   the differences between files in two
>   server folders, **in a server folder and
>   a local folder**, or in two local
>   folders.

Comment: Not really what I was looking for, but your answer helped point me in the right direction - the Compare option in the source explorer lets you see what has changed in your working copy from the last changeset.

Answer (score 0):

From the header toolbar click the "Find Chengsets" option (it is between History and Branch options), it will open a dialog box, on that fill your required attributes and click Find button on that dialog box.